# How get IR value from llvm.dbg.declare

Tags: metadata, llvm, llvm-ir

Given a `llvm.dbg.declare`, how can I get its llvm value?

e.g.

```
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata !{i32** %r}, metadata !23), !dbg !24
```

I want get the Value `i32** %r`, not the metadata `!{i32** %r}`.

Please give me the code!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`metadata !{i32** %r}` is the 1st operand of the call instruction, and `i32** %r` is the 1st operand of the metadata. So something like this should work:

```
CallInst I = ... // get the @llvm.dbg.declare call
Value* referredValue = cast<MDNode>(I->getOperand(0))->getOperand(0);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! But we need add a cast :`Value* referredValue = cast<MDNode>(I->getOperand(0))->getOperand(0);`

Comment: @blankboy2011 oops, forgot about that. I've edited your comment into my post, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In later versions of LLVM, it is not allowed to cast `Metadata` from `Value` (I was on LLVM 7.0.1). Special classes `MetadataAsValue` and `ValueAsMetadata` are required for the cast.

```
CallInst *CI;      /* Call to llvm.dbg.declare */
AllocaInst *AI;    /* AllocaInst is the result */

Metadata *Meta = cast<MetadataAsValue>(CI->getOperand(0))->getMetadata();
if (isa<ValueAsMetadata>(Meta)) {
  Value *V = cast <ValueAsMetadata>(Meta)->getValue();
  AI = cast<AllocaInst>(V);
}
```

As you can see, the `AllocaInst` is wrapped inside `ValueAsMetadata` and then `MetadataAsValue`.

If you also want the get the `DIVariable` from this call.

```
DIVariable *V = cast<DIVariable>(cast<MetadataAsValue>(CI->getOperand(1))->getMetadata());
```

Comment: This solution works also with LLVM 12.0.0, and I have been through lot of pain to make it work myself, but couldn't. Thanks a lot!!