# LLVM traverse the IR and look for all calls to @llvm.dbg.declare

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am writing an LLVM pass that bookeeps the number of declared variables in an openCL Kernel. To do so, I need to enable debugging information and access the `@llvm.dbg.declare` info.

I iterate through all the instructions of a function and I use the `isa<CallInst>` template to identify the calling instructions.

Now there are two cases here, I can have either

`call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata float addrspace(1)** %4, metadata !20, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !21`

or

`%6 = call i32 @get_global_id(i32 0), !dbg !25`

How can I check that a `CallInst` has metadata associated with it, that is, it has `@llvm.dbg.declare` inside and then how do I extract the name of the variable declaration (I suspect via a `getOperand()` method ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it has @llvm.dbg.declare inside"?

Comment: @arrowd I compile with `-o0 -g` to generate debugging information

Comment: Instead you can IntrinsicInst* psIntri = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::IntrinsicInst>(&inst) and if it is not null then check and compare psIntri->getIntrinsicID() == llvm::Intrinsic::dbg_declare.  for metadata extraction see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947606/how-get-ir-value-from-llvm-dbg-declare  P.S. may be some easier methods are there for what you are trying to accomplice.

Comment: @ChiragPatel I actually ended up doing something similar to the answer you referenced. I will post a complete answer later today. Thank you!